# Magento Updating Products with csv overwrites Image

Tags: magento, csv, image-uploading

On Magento 1.9 I managed to upload several products via csv including images with Dataflow - Profiles.

Now I'd like to update for example all the descriptions. But when I upload the CSV file, it overwrites my images.

1. When I leave the path media/import it imports the same image a
   second time. Now the product has the same image stored twice.
2. When I write the path /0/5/imagename.jpg where magento automatically
   saved the image, it gives me a "images doesn't exist" error.
3. when I leave the "image" field empty, it sets the default image to "none"
   and shows no image in the frontend.
4. When I delete the whole cell
   for images, it gives me a "broken link" symbol in the product
   details page.

How can I update product details without messing with my images? Sorry if I missed something?

Comment: Have you considered magmi? It has an update option although I don't know if it will ignore existing images if you leave things blank.

Comment: Hi if you have your product images imported than next time when you will try to import csv dont include image columns in that csv . That will not generate any error. You can just use the columns which you want with the sku.